# Setup Wizard

Tags: c#, deployment

I am using the Setup Wizard to package my windows form app however when installing I get prompted to install the .NET 3.5 framework even though my app is built on 2.0 and the 3.5 framework is not ticked in the prereqs section of the setup project.

Why is it asking for .NET 3.5?

Comment: Are you building setup package from Visual Studio?  If so, what version and how?

Comment: Yes, that would be important to know.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I have manually changed the framework version under Launch Conditions.